# Internal linking in the html using regex for predefined set of text, url

Tags: python, html, regex, pattern-matching, anchor

I have html text something like:

```
<p>Walmart **big data** into the DNA of Walmart.</p>
<h2><strong>Social **Big Data** Solutions</strong></h2>
<h2>Social Big Data Solutions</h2> 
<a href="big data"><strong>Social Big Data Solutions</strong></a>
<a href="big data">Social Big Data Solutions</a>
<p>Test big data</p>
```

I need to add internal link to all the text matching "big data", ie,I need to select "big data" inside all the html tags except `<a>` tag using a regular expression and replace with internal link `<a href="/bigdata/">big data</a>`

I have a regular expression `(?!<a[^>]*>)(\b(?:big data)\b)(?![^<]*<\/a>)`   it won't matches content inside `<a href="big data">Social Big Data Solutions</a>`, but will match attribute inside `<a href="big data"><strong>Social Big Data Solutions</strong></a>`, thus the internal linking  became `<a>` inside `<a>`.

If you guys have any suggestion for a regex, please help. Here a snippet http://regexr.com/3f3bn that I have tried.

Comment: Check [`\bbig data\b(?!(?:(?!<\/?a\b)[\s\S])*<\/a>|[^<]*>)`](https://regex101.com/r/bMkmM9/1). However, you should think twice before using it in a real project, parsing HTML with regex is not safe.

Comment: IMHO, this sounds like a job for xpath rather than regexes. I suggest you post a similar question asking instead for a way to use xpath to update entities not contained within an <a>.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your solution work perfectly. Yes, I need to find a solution using xpath instead of regex. Thanks

Comment: @ghwp. Thanks for your suggestion regarding xpath.

Comment: Then what is the programming language?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew python.

Comment: Then use BeautifulSoup or any other HTML parser and do the job properly.